# Store the results of a sub-query for use in multiple joins

Tags: mysql, caching

I have the following MySQL query, which produces the result I want:

```
SELECT
  `l`.`status`,
  `l`.`acquired_by`, `a`.`name` AS 'acquired_by_name',
  `l`.`researcher`,  `r`.`name` AS 'researcher_name',
  `l`.`surveyor`,    `s`.`name` AS 'surveyor_name'
FROM `leads` `l`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS 'id', 'Unassigned' AS 'name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `id`, `name`
  FROM `web_users`
) `r` ON `r`.`id` = `l`.`researcher`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS 'id', 'Unassigned' AS 'name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `id`, `name`
  FROM `web_users`
) `s` ON `s`.`id` = `l`.`surveyor`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT '0' AS 'id', 'Unassigned' AS 'name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `id`, `name`
  FROM `web_users`
) `a` ON `a`.`id` = `l`.`acquired_by`
WHERE `l`.`id` = 566
```

But as you can see, it has the same sub-query in it three times. Is there any way to execute this query once and store the result, so I can `LEFT JOIN` with the cached results instead of executing the same query three times?

I have tried storing it in a variable:

```
SET @usercache = (
  SELECT '0' AS 'id', 'Unassigned' AS 'name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `id`, `name`
  FROM `web_users`
)
```

...but this gives me an error:

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

...and some Googling on this error has left me none the wiser.

Does anyone know how I can make this query more efficient? Or am I just worrying about something that doesn't matter anyway?

I am using PHP/MySQLi if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the subqueries? How about this:

```
SELECT
  `l`.`status`,
  `l`.`acquired_by`, COALESCE(`a`.`name`, 'Unassigned') AS 'acquired_by_name',
  `l`.`researcher`,  COALESCE(`r`.`name`, 'Unassigned') AS 'researcher_name',
  `l`.`surveyor`,    COALESCE(`s`.`name`, 'Unassigned') AS 'surveyor_name'
FROM `leads` `l`
LEFT JOIN `web_users` `r` ON `r`.`id` = `l`.`researcher`
LEFT JOIN `web_users` `s` ON `s`.`id` = `l`.`surveyor`
LEFT JOIN `web_users` `a` ON `a`.`id` = `l`.`acquired_by`
WHERE `l`.`id` = 566
```

Comment: Of course this is a much better way to do it. Just testing... ;-) Actually I have never ever had cause to use `COALESCE()` before and I had completely forgotten about it's existence.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run it once - you are actually using it three times to get three different results...

Comment: It will always return the same set of results unless the `web_users` table was modified while the query was executing, although this is highly unlikely. The only reason the sub query existed was to add a row with an `id` of `0` for unassigned items.